# F# How to call let function correctly? Function call in [<EntryPoint>] isn't working

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, function, f#

I am new to F#. What I am trying to do is to call `test` more than once to print out `Hello World`. In this example, I want to call `test` three times. When I run the code it only prints to console once. Even without the `test` call, it runs. I have the following code:

```
open System

let test =
    let mutable output = ""
    output <- "Hello World"

    printfn "%s" output

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    test
    test
    test
    ignore(Console.ReadKey())
    0
```

Comment: If I may ask: what's the point of making `output` mutable, rather than just doing `let output = "Hello World"`?

Comment: You might want to try looking a bit into the syntax of F# as well. You're sticking way too close to C#-like coding. Try http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/learning-fsharp/ for a primer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want `test` to be a function, declare it like this:

```
let test () =
```

… and call it like this:

```
test ()
```

A function always receives one argument and returns one value. Where you see more than one parameter, these are curried into a series of functions that each receive one argument. That's why you see signatures like `int -> string -> string`.

If you have no need of parameters, as in this case, you use unit, which is represented by `()`.

Comment: Great! Thank you for your fast response!

Answer (score 1):

`test` as it written is not a function - it is a value of type `unit`. You have to add parenthesis:

```
let test () =
    let mutable output = ""
    output <- "Hello World"

    printfn "%s" output
```

And call it this way:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    test()
    test()
    test()
    ignore(Console.ReadKey())
    0
```

Answer (score 0):

`test` is not a function, it's a variable, so you can not call it. You can only access its value, which is `()`. Accessing a value without doing anything with it does not affect the behavior of the program in any way, which is why writing `test` in your `main` function has no effect.

If you want to be able to call `test` you need to make it a function by giving it a parameter. Since you don't seem to actually want any parameters, you can use `unit` as the parameter type. That would look like this:

```
let test () =
    let mutable output = ""
    output <- "Hello World"
    printfn "%s" output
```

And the corresponding call would look like this:

```
test ()
```